# Jasmine 2.3 and Ext JS 5.0.1

Tags: extjs, jasmine

I am trying to test an Ext JS 5.0.1 application with Jasmine 2.3.4.  I keep getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined".  It is as though it is not seeing describe, it, and other global functions.  If I switch out the Jasmine files to 1.3, then it does see these global functions.  I want to use the newest version of Jasmine and furthermore, I am not sure 1.3 plays well with Ext JS 5.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  Code snippets below:

specrunner.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>


      <title>Test Application</title>

        <!--Jasmine Files -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app_name/app/js/jasmine/jasmine.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/app_name/app/js/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/app_name/app/js/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>

        <!-- ExtJS Files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn-tst.corporate.com/LNF/4/4.0.1/extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn-tst.corporate.com/LNF/4/4.0.1/extjs/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/ext-theme-classic.js"></script>

        <!-- Jasmine Test Case File -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/app_name/app/js/spec/AppSpec.js"></script>

        <!-- app Test Case File -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/app_name/app/js/test/app.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

app.js (for testing)

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig ({enabled: true});

// Loading different components like controller, model, view..
Ext.application ({
    models: [ 'Trip' ],
    stores: [ 'Trips' ],
 //   views: [ 'simpleTrip' ], Views are throwing an error
    autoCreateViewport: false,
    name: 'carrier360',

    // using the Launch method of Application object to execute the Jasmine Test Cases
    launch: function () {
        debugger;
        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv ();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter ();
        jasmineEnv.addReporter (htmlReporter);
        jasmineEnv.execute ();
    }

});
```

AppSpec.js

```
describe ("ExtJS App Test Suite", function () {
debugger;

beforeEach (function () {
    // Initializing the mainPanel
    debugger;
    tripsStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup ('Trips');
    simpleTrip = Ext.create ('app.view.simpleTrip');

    controller = Ext.create ('view.controller.tripController');
});

/* Test if View is created Successfully.*/
it ('View is loaded', function () {
    debugger;
    expect (simpleTrip != null).toBeTruthy ();
});

/* Test if store is loaded successfully.*/
it ('Store shouldnâ€™t be null', function () {
    debugger;
    expect (tripsStore != null).toBeTruthy();
});

/* Test controller is initialized successfully.*/
it ('Controller shouldnâ€™t be null', function () {
    debugger;
    expect (controller != null).toBeTruthy();
});

});
```

Any suggestions on why describe and other functions are not visible would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove Ext from the page? Still the same issue?

Comment: After much head pounding, I found that 1.3 has less files than 2.3.  Simple as that.  I updated specrunner.jsp to include boot.js and jasmine_favicon.png and it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Descibre*, *it*, ... are no longuer defined in *jasmine.js* but instead in the *boot.js* included with jasmine library.

Comment: Thanks PomPom.  When moving from 1.3 to 2.3.x, include boot.js and the code that I have above in the launch function is no longer necessary.